# sometimes showDialog doesn't work

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a **fragmentActivity** that use **startActivityForResult(intent, getCode)** to call an activity that sends some files via ftp.

In the method **onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)** shows the result of the operation (failure, success, no internet, etc...) using a **dialog**.

The dialog is called like this:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(LLAVE_TITULO, alertTitulo);
bundle.putString(LLAVE_MENSAJE, alertMensaje);
showDialog(DIALOG_RESPUESTA, bundle);
```

and the **onCreateDialog** method is basic

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle)
{
    Builder mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    mAlertDialog.setTitle(bundle.getString(LLAVE_TITULO));
    mAlertDialog.setMessage(bundle.getString(LLAVE_MENSAJE));
    mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Aceptar",null);
    return mAlertDialog.create();
}
```

Everything is working ok, but I noticed when I show and dismiss the dialog really fast (the faster i can, once or twice per second) in some point the dialog doesn't show anymore until I close the activity and start it again...

What is happening here? How can I really be sure that the dialog will show?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

activity calls onCreateDialog() one times for each dialog.. 
so.. I think you should use DialogInterface.OnShowListener for dialog view widgets validation